# VBA Access acLink database

Tags: ms-access, vba

I am trying to create a main database that link other databases. What is the best way to link them, so later I could write queries and access information later? I am using a iteration to create a new database per year.

```
For i = StartYear To EndYear
    strFile = "mar31_wts_" & i & ".csv"
    ' create the database
    strDBPath = "Desktop\DATA\" & i & "db.accdb"
    DAO.CreateDatabase(strDBPath, dbLangGeneral).Close

    ' open the database in a new Access Application
    Set app = New Application
    app.OpenCurrentDatabase strDBPath

    strPathFile = strPath & strFile

    ' import the csv file into that database
    app.DoCmd.TransferText acImportDelim, acSpreadsheetTypeText, strFile, strPathFile, blnHasFieldNames
    'CurrentDb.Execute "ALTER TABLE " & strFile & " Alter Column AGE TEXT(100)"

    ' close the database and the Access application
    app.Quit acQuitSaveNone

    'Link Database
    'DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink, ???


Next i
```

Comment: You shouldn't create a database per year, not even a table per year, but add a field to your table and fill this with the year.

Comment: @Gustav I'm OK with a database per year.

Comment: Please expand on your question. What programming problem are you having? What's not working?

Comment: I agree with Gustav.  How much data do you have in a year that it would justify a new database every year.  If you add a field for the year, you could query on that field for that year.  No need to jump around to another database for each year.   And what if you wanted a range of years?   Keep it simple.

Comment: There is a few million rows and 4 columns per year. I am having difficulties  linking the main database with these per year.